# When exactly my programmatically added views will gone from activity and no longer accessible?

Tags: android, android-view, android-memory

I have a RadioGroup in my app and I add radiobuttons to it in my java code. I wonder when this buttons will be removed from my activity?
I mean when I close app ? Or when I use my back button in phone? Or when I restart my phone?

Comment: They are there as long as the activity is in memory; Android caches activities for quicker reopening. Most activities load a layout in `onCreate`, which I think will clear all old Views and put new ones in. There is, however, a chance that the activity will be unloaded the instant or disappears from screen (low memory, a certain setting in Developer Options etc.), so I wouldn't trust them being there any longer.

Comment: once the activity is destroyed, your view objects qualify for garbage collection as long as they are not identified as static.

Comment: is finish() method will call onDestry() and then onCreate() ?

Comment: `onDestroy()` is called when Android thinks that it's time to say goodbye to the activity, for e.g. the reasons explained in my last comment.